# In a dict of dicts, how do you emulate Perl's auto-vivification behavior?

Tags: python, dictionary, autovivification

Both Google and the online docs are not delivering much insight on my query, so I thought I would ask the community here.

In Perl, you can easily setup a hash-of-a-hash-of-a-hash and test the final key like so:

```
my $hash = {};
$hash{"element1"}{"sub1"}{"subsub1"} = "value1";
if (exists($hash{"element1"}{"sub1"}{"subsub1"})) {
   print "found value\n";
}
```

What's the 'best-practice' equivalent in Python?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The closest equivalent is probably something like the following:

```
import collections

def hasher():
  return collections.defaultdict(hasher)

hash = hasher()
hash['element1']['sub1']['subsub1'] = 'value1'
if 'subsub1' in hash['element1']['sub1']:
  print 'found value'
```

Comment: Note that `if sub1 in hash['phony']` creates a key `'phony'`. This might be problematic, especially since the OP wants to test if keys exist...

Comment: @~unutbu: the OP asks: "test the *final* key", therefore `hash['element1']['sub1'] = dict(subsub1='value1')` will do.

Comment: Thanks, this is quite helpful.

Answer (score 5):

As to whether this is a best practice in Python is up to debate:

```
hash = {}
hash['element1', 'sub1', 'subsub1'] = 'value'
if ('element1', 'sub1', 'subsub1') in hash:
    print "found value"
```

But, it certainly works and is very elegant, if it works for you.

The major drawback is that you don't have intermediate access. You *can't* do:

```
if ('element1', 'sub1') in hash:
   print "found value"
```

Comment: You should explain what's happening.  This is a single hash/dict with a 3-element [tuple](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#tuple) as a key.  Really not the same thing, though you did somewhat indicate that with your second example.

Comment: Interesting way to handle the "drawback" (if you consider it to be such) in Alex Martelli's answer, pointed out by ~unutbu.

Comment: Indeed, this wasn't what I was looking for - but interesting nonetheless.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import defaultdict

tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)

t = tree()

t[1][2][3] = 4
t[1][3][3] = 5
t[1][2]['test'] = 6
```

from [wikipedia Autovivification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification)

Comment: Besides using `lambda`, how is this different from the accepted answer 3 years ago?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'll get any agreement, but this is how I typically declare dictionaries of dictionaries:

```
someObj = {
  'element1': {
    'sub1': {
      'subsub1': 'value1'
    }
  }
}
```

As for checking for the presence of an element, I agree with this approach:

```
try:
  someObj['element1']['sub1']['subsub1']
except KeyError:
  print('no value found')
else:
  print('found value')
```