# Generating dictionary keys on the fly

Tags: python, dictionary, decorator

Working with deeply nested python dicts, I would like to be able to assign values in such a data structure like this:

```
  mydict[key][subkey][subkey2]="value"
```

without having to check that mydict[key] etc. are actually set to be a dict, e.g. using

```
  if not key in mydict: mydict[key]={}
```

The creation of subdictionaries should happen on the fly. What is the most elegant way to allow something equivalent - maybe using decorators on the standard `<type 'dict'>`?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122566/in-a-python-dict-of-dicts-how-do-you-emulate-perls-auto-vivification-behavior/3122575#3122575

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
class D(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = D()
        return self[key]

d = D()
d['a']['b']['c'] = 3
```

Comment: You have to be careful with this. `d['a'] = 2 d['a']['b'] = 2` will fail.

Comment: Yes, but that is implied in my question - I am asking for a mixed type of dicts and values.

Comment: To solve the case d['a'] = 2 d['a']['b'] = 2, I would even write class D(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = type(self)()
        return value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        values = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        if isinstance(values, dict):
            values = SafeDict(values)
        if isinstance(values, list):
            for i, v in enumerate(values):
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    values[i] = SafeDict(v)
        return values

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19829714/355230) for a slightly improved implementation of this in `class Vividict`.

Answer (score 14):

You could use a tuple as the key for the dict and then you don't have to worry about subdictionaries at all:

```
mydict[(key,subkey,subkey2)] = "value"
```

Alternatively, if you really need to have subdictionaries for some reason you could use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

For two levels this is straightforward:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(dict)
>>> d['key']['subkey'] = 'value'
>>> d['key']['subkey']
'value'
```

For three it's slightly more complex:

```
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
>>> d['key']['subkey']['subkey2'] = 'value'
>>> d['key']['subkey']['subkey2']
'value'
```

Four and more levels are left as an exercise for the reader.  :-)

Comment: Amazing. I'm glad I asked, if only because I don't understand how I could miss this. :)

Comment: Good answer. Can you provide how to do it with a `defaultdict`? Nesting once is easy: `mydict = defaultdict(dict)`. But is there an elegant solution for nesting twice?

Comment: @jellybean - just added the three level solution; it's not too bad.

Comment: Hmm, the tuple solution does break the ability to iterate over the subdictionaries though, doesn't it?

Comment: @relet - it does which is why I also gave the `defaultdict` solution too.

Answer (score 3):

I like Dave's answer better, but here's an alternative.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))
>>> d['a']['b'] += 1
>>> d
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x652f0>, {'a': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'b': 1})})
>>> d['a']['b']
1
```

http://tumble.philadams.net/post/85269428/python-nested-defaultdicts

It's definitely not pretty to have to use lambdas to implements the inner defaulted collections, but apparently necessary.

Comment: Lambdas are never necessary: you can always use a named function instead. In this case using a named function would at least mean the `repr` has something a bit more meaningful than `lambda`.