# Generate a list of variables in SymPy

Tags: python, list, variables, sympy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SymPy - Arbitrary number of Symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492944/sympy-arbitrary-number-of-symbols)

I am trying to create a system of equations which is formed through iteration. 
Each equation is generated with:

`summation(binomial(n,i) * (1-t) ** (n-i) * t ** i * P[i]) - V[j]`

where all `V[j]` are given as input. The idea is to use the system of equations created around `P[i]` to then solve for every `P[i]` but to do so, they must be sympy symbol objects, and I'm not sure how to generate such a list.

Is it possible to have a nameless list or generate a list of symbols?

Please let me know if the question begs for clarification, I had a hard time putting it into words.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492944/sympy-arbitrary-number-of-symbols), in particular the `sympy.symbols` and `symnpy.numbered_symbols` answers, help?

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I'm looking for! However, my isympy does not follow the behavior of the documentation. In the docs, symbols('a0:10') should yield a tuple of numbered Symbols. When I run this, I get symbols with the names 'a', '0', ':', and so forth. What's wrong here?

Comment: Works for me, so at a guess, maybe you're using an old version of `sympy`?  (`print sympy.__version__` will tell you.  If you're pre-0.7.2, then upgrade; I can't remember when symbol numbering was introduced.)

Comment: That is the behavior of a rather old version of SymPy (I think 0.6.7 and earlier).

Comment: Early version in apt-get. I installed 0.7.2 from source and it works now. Thanks so much!