# Difference between var and Symbol in sympy

Tags: python, var, sympy, symbols

Is there any difference between the two methods `var` and `symbol` in the `sympy` module in python? cause both are working the same way. I googled it and I did not find a detailed explanation for a difference. Are they really the exact same thing or one of them is actually using the other or what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an answer to that in the [FAQ](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Faq#what-is-the-best-way-to-create-symbols).
Basically, `var(x)` is equal to `x = Symbol('x')`, but the former doesn't force you to type `x` twice, while the latter is more explicit. `var` calls `symbols`, according to the [docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#var).

`Symbol` also takes options, as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31916910/4085591) post.
You can pass assumptions (like `positive=True`), classes (if you want to create a named expression for example) or `seq=<True|False>` if you want the symbol to be an iterator.

There is also `symbols`, which can create tuples of symbols quickly, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9493306/4085591): `a = symbols('a0:%d' % 5)`, which creates a tuple `(a0, a1, a2, a3, a4)`.

Comment: All what you mentioned is in both `var` and `symbols`, I may then adjust the question, Is there any difference between `symbols` and `var`?

Comment: You are right, I didn't look deep enough at first. `var` calls `symbols`, so they are equal. See the updated answer.