# Setting a value in a nested Python dictionary given a list of indices and value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to programmatically set a value in a dictionary, potentially nested, given a list of indices and a value.

So for example, let's say my list of indices is:

```
['person', 'address', 'city']
```

and the value is

```
'New York'
```

I want as a result a dictionary object like:

```
{ 'Person': { 'address': { 'city': 'New York' } }
```

Basically, the list represents a 'path' into a nested dictionary.

I think I can construct the dictionary itself, but where I'm stumbling is how to set the value. Obviously if I was just writing code for this manually it would be:

```
dict['Person']['address']['city'] = 'New York'
```

But how do I index into the dictionary and set the value like that programmatically if I just have a list of the indices and the value?

Python

Comment: What's wrong with `dict[x][y][z] = value`?  Where do you get `value` from? What's with the weird format?

Comment: @kreativitea It's wrong because he may have variable-length number of nested keys.

Comment: You may be able to avoid nesting by using tuple keys:  `d[tuple(da_list)] = value`

Comment: For greater context, I have to take numerous strings in the format 'key1:key2:key3=value' and turn this into a nested dictionary, where key1 is at the first level, key2 at the second etc. The strings might have one key, two keys, three keys. So a bit of string splitting gets me a list of keys, and a value and where I go from there is the next question...

Comment: The question is: "why do you have to turn this into a nested dictionary?" Are you sure you really need a nested dictionary? Things like this can often be coded better with tuple keys, or other data structures.

Comment: Ultimately the constructed object will be spit out as JSON...where the hierarchy is necessary. But if there's a better way to go from my strings to a stringified JSON object I'm very open to it :) I may be over-engineering the solution!?

Comment: What's wrong with just d["key1:key2:key3"] = value?

Comment: If the problem is the json conversion, then you may be able to use tuple-keys internally and only convert to a nested structure when you have to produce the json.
@ekhumoro I imagine that the program that receives the data expects something nested as shown in the question, so using a string would not produce an usable output anyway(even if valid json).

Comment: @Bakuriu. Yes, my comment was a bit rhetorical: the OP hasn't fully defined his real problem.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Something like this could help:

```
def nested_set(dic, keys, value):
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        dic = dic.setdefault(key, {})
    dic[keys[-1]] = value
```

And you can use it like this:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> nested_set(d, ['person', 'address', 'city'], 'New York')
>>> d
{'person': {'address': {'city': 'New York'}}}
```

Comment: Any clue please why this works? (I've tried it and works) And why a pure for loop does not?

Comment: @charisz This works because inside the `for` look you re-assign the `dic` variable to point to the inner dictionary. In the example, when `nested_set` is set, initially you have `dic == d`. Then the `for` loop performs the call `dic = dic.setdefault("person", {})` which adds the pair `"person": {}` to `d` and also *returns the referenced `{}`*. Now `dic is d["person"]`, so the next loop sets the key `address` in the inner dictionary, setting `dic` to point to the inner-inner dictionary. Etc.  The last key is treated in a special way because you don't want to create dictionaries anymore.

Comment: @Bakuriu It will break for the attached case as it doesn't replace for a pre-assigned key. Refer my implementation for the correct behavior https://imgur.com/a/pST93yQ

Comment: @nehemiah That's a different behaviour than what the question required. As you can see it adds quite a bit of complexity in the implementation.

Answer (score 8):

I took the freedom to extend the code from [the answer of Bakuriu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13688108/3469861). Therefore upvotes on this are optional, as his code is in and of itself a witty solution, which I wouldn't have thought of.

```
def nested_set(dic, keys, value, create_missing=True):
    d = dic
    for key in keys[:-1]:
        if key in d:
            d = d[key]
        elif create_missing:
            d = d.setdefault(key, {})
        else:
            return dic
    if keys[-1] in d or create_missing:
        d[keys[-1]] = value
    return dic
```

When setting `create_missing` to True, you're making sure to only set already existing values:

```
# Trying to set a value of a nonexistent key DOES NOT create a new value
print(nested_set({"A": {"B": 1}}, ["A", "8"], 2, False))
>>> {'A': {'B': 1}}

# Trying to set a value of an existent key DOES create a new value
print(nested_set({"A": {"B": 1}}, ["A", "8"], 2, True))
>>> {'A': {'B': 1, '8': 2}}

# Set the value of an existing key
print(nested_set({"A": {"B": 1}}, ["A", "B"], 2))
>>> {'A': {'B': 2}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another option:

```
from collections import defaultdict
recursivedict = lambda: defaultdict(recursivedict)
mydict = recursivedict()
```

I originally got this from here: *[Set nested dict value and create intermediate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218486/set-nested-dict-value-and-create-intermediate-keys/10218517#10218517)*.

It is quite clever and elegant if you ask me.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you probably want to look at [setdefault](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html).

As a function I'd write it as

```
def get_leaf_dict(dct, key_list):
    res=dct
    for key in key_list:
        res=res.setdefault(key, {})
    return res
```

This would be used as:

```
get_leaf_dict( dict, ['Person', 'address', 'city']) = 'New York'
```

This could be cleaned up with error handling and such. Also using `*args` rather than a single key-list argument might be nice; but the idea is that
you can iterate over the keys, pulling up the appropriate dictionary at each level.

Comment: And thank you for this...Bakuriu's answer is slightly more comprehensive/concise, but you were on the same track and I appreciate how quickly you replied.

Comment: I get a `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call` in Python 3 for `get_leaf_dict( dict, ['Person', 'address', 'city']) = 'New York'`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my simple solution: just write

```
terms = ['person', 'address', 'city'] 
result = nested_dict(3, str)
result[terms] = 'New York'  # as easy as it can be
```

You can even do:

```
terms = ['John', 'Tinkoff', '1094535332']  # account in Tinkoff Bank
result = nested_dict(3, float)
result[terms] += 2375.30
```

Now the backstage:

```
from collections import defaultdict


class nesteddict(defaultdict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, list):
            d = self
            for i in key:
                d = defaultdict.__getitem__(d, i)
            return d
        else:
            return defaultdict.__getitem__(self, key)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, list):
            d = self[key[:-1]]
            defaultdict.__setitem__(d, key[-1], value)
        else:
            defaultdict.__setitem__(self, key, value)


def nested_dict(n, type):
    if n == 1:
        return nesteddict(type)
    else:
        return nesteddict(lambda: nested_dict(n-1, type))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use these pair of methods

```
def gattr(d, *attrs):
    """
    This method receives a dict and list of attributes to return the innermost value of the give dict
    """
    try:
        for at in attrs:
            d = d[at]
        return d
    except:
        return None


def sattr(d, *attrs):
    """
    Adds "val" to dict in the hierarchy mentioned via *attrs
    For ex:
    sattr(animals, "cat", "leg","fingers", 4) is equivalent to animals["cat"]["leg"]["fingers"]=4
    This method creates necessary objects until it reaches the final depth
    This behaviour is also known as autovivification and plenty of implementation are around
    This implementation addresses the corner case of replacing existing primitives
    https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250#gistcomment-1779319
    """
    for attr in attrs[:-2]:
        # If such key is not found or the value is primitive supply an empty dict
        if d.get(attr) is None or isinstance(d.get(attr), dict):
            d[attr] = {}
        d = d[attr]
    d[attrs[-2]] = attrs[-1]
```

Comment: Don't use a bare `except:`, it should **never** appear in code. You want to use `except KeyError` instead. Also your solution breaks if someones uses a different mapping type than `dict`. You may want to use [`abc.MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping) or [`abc.Mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Mapping)

Answer (score 2):

The *dotty_dict* library for Python 3 can do this. See documentation, *[Dotty Dict](https://dotty-dict.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)* for more clarity.

```
from dotty_dict import dotty

dot = dotty()
string = '.'.join(['person', 'address', 'city'])
dot[string] = 'New York'

print(dot)
```

Output:

```
{'person': {'address': {'city': 'New York'}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variant of [Bakuriu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687924/setting-a-value-in-a-nested-python-dictionary-given-a-list-of-indices-and-value/13688108#13688108) that doesn't rely on a separate function:

```
keys = ['Person', 'address', 'city']
value = 'New York'

nested_dict = {}

# Build nested dictionary up until 2nd to last key
# (Effectively nested_dict['Person']['address'] = {})
sub_dict = nested_dict
for key_ind, key in enumerate(keys[:-1]):
    if not key_ind:
        # Point to newly added piece of dictionary
        sub_dict = nested_dict.setdefault(key, {})
    else:
        # Point to newly added piece of sub-dictionary
        # that is also added to original dictionary
        sub_dict = sub_dict.setdefault(key, {})
# Add value to last key of nested structure of keys
# (Effectively nested_dict['Person']['address']['city'] = value)
sub_dict[keys[-1]] = value

print(nested_dict)

>>> {'Person': {'address': {'city': 'New York'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty good use case for a recursive function. So you can do something like this:

```py
def parse(l: list, v: str) -> dict:
    copy = dict()
    k, *s = l
    if len(s) > 0:
        copy[k] = parse(s, v)
    else:
        copy[k] = v
    return copy
```

This effectively pops off the first value of the passed list `l` as a key for the dict `copy` that we initialize, then runs the remaining list through the same function, creating a new key under *that* key until there's nothing left in the list, whereupon it assigns the last value to the `v` param.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your own helper class to make your code clear.
dict_helper.py:

```
from collections import UserDict

# reference: https://realpython.com/inherit-python-dict/

class DictHelper(UserDict):
    """
    reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491287/elegant-way-to-check-if-a-nested-key-exists-in-a-dict
    """

    def has_key(self, path: str | list):
        keys = path.split('.') if isinstance(path, str) else path

        val = self.data
        for key in keys:
            if not key in val:
                return False
            else:
                val = val[key]
        return True

    # Throwing in this approach for nested get for the heck of it...
    def get_key(self, path: str | list, default=None):
        keys = path.split('.') if isinstance(path, str) else path

        val = self.data
        for key in keys:
            if key in val:
                val = val[key]
            else:
                return default
        return val

    def set_key(self, path: str | list, value):
        keys = path.split('.') if isinstance(path, str) else path

        val = self.data
        for key in keys[:-1]:
            val.setdefault(key, {})
            val = val[key]
        val[keys[-1]] = value
```

main.py:

```
from dict_helper import DictHelper

# way1
d = DictHelper({})
d.set_key(['person', 'address', 'city'], 'New York')
print(d)

# or way2
d = DictHelper({})
d.set_key('person.address.city', 'New York')
print(d) 
# both way has the same result
# output={'person': {'address': {'city': 'New York'}}}
```

you can also use your own helper functions and helper classes in future projects.

### new update 17 Feb 2024:

there is a very [good library](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-benedict) exists that can handle your class easier. just install it by below command:

```
pip install "python-benedict[all or io for this project]"
```

now you can define this class very easily:

```
from collections import UserDict
from benedict import benedict


class DictHelper(UserDict):

def __init__(self, d: dict = None):
    super().__init__(d)
    self.d = benedict().from_json(self.data)

@staticmethod
def __keypath__(path: str | list):
    return path if isinstance(path, str) else '.'.join(path)

def has_key(self, path: str | list):
    return self.__keypath__(path) in self.d

def get_key(self, path: str | list):
    return self.d[self.__keypath__(path)]

def set_key(self, path: str | list, value=None):
    self.d[self.__keypath__(path)] = value
```

Answer (score -5):

This is much easier in Perl:

```
my %hash;
$hash{"aaa"}{"bbb"}{"ccc"}=1;  # auto creates each of the intermediate levels
                               # of the hash (aka: dict or associated array)
```