# Python configure dict structure

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a way to save a python dict structure in config then access it?

For example:

```
dict = {'root': {'category': {'item': 'test'}}}

# in my config
key = 'some string here'

print (dict[key])

# output
>> test
```

Solution thanks to answers below:

```
from functools import reduce
import json

dict = {'root': {'category': {'item': 'test'}}}

# you can put this in your config.ini file
map = '["root", "category", "item"]'

print (reduce(lambda d, k: d[k], json.loads(map), dict))

#output
test
```

Comment: Related: [Acces python nested dictionary items via a list of keys](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14692690)

Comment: It is very unclear to me what is being asked. Is "key" something like "root.category.item"?

Comment: Why in the world would you expect the key `'some string here'` to access (or map to) the value stored in `dict['root']['category']['item']`?

Comment: because I'm iterating a set of dicts that have different structure and keys for the same value being extracted. So instead of using a custom function for each dict structure, I would like to use a global config to predefine each dict structure and keymap.

Comment: @Andrei Stalbe: No need to encode the list as JSON and then parse it back, just use it as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `reduce()` function or the [pickle protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the pickle protocol. You can store virtually anything using that.
documentation on pickling:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html