# How to get the inner indexes of a nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like

```
A = {1:{1:50,2:60,5:90},2:{7:55,10:102},4:{10:100,12:40}}
```

How can i access the inner indexes of the dictionary i.e the keys 1,2,5  or the keys 10 and 12
I mean i want access these elements to store them in specific places of an array, but while using a loop, since some keys are absent, there is some kind of an error.(when i tried using A[i][j] in my nested loops).
How to tackle this unevenness of keyss

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access python nested dictionary items via a list of keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-python-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys)

Comment: Are you trying to convert a sparse matrix into a nonsparse one?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to access value for specific keys,you can do that using `A[outer_key][inner_key]`

for example

```
>>> A[1][1]
50
>>> A[2][10]
102
```

If you want to iterate over all the keys , you can use `for` as shown below.

```
>>> A
{1: {1: 50, 2: 60, 5: 90}, 2: {10: 102, 7: 55}, 4: {10: 100, 12: 40}}
>>> for outer_key in A:
...     print 'Outer Key = ',outer_key
...     for inner_key in A[outer_key]:
...             print '%d,%d' % (inner_key,A[outer_key][inner_key])
... 
Outer Key =  1
1,50
2,60
5,90
Outer Key =  2
10,102
7,55
Outer Key =  4
10,100
12,40
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the built in iterators to accomplish this task.

```
A = {1:{1:50,2:60,5:90},2:{7:55,10:102},4:{10:100,12:40}}

myArray = list()

for innerDict in A.values():
    for value in innerDict.values():
        myArray.append(value)

print (myArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will iterate through the structure and fill the values into a `numpy` array:

```
A = {1:{1:50,2:60,5:90},2:{7:55,10:102},4:{10:100,12:40}}
B = numpy.zeros((4, 12))

for i, row in A.items():
    for j, value in row.items():
        B[i-1, j-1] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = {1:{1:50,2:60,5:90},2:{7:55,10:102},4:{10:100,12:40}}

values =[ x for y in A.itervalues() for x in y.itervalues()]
[50, 60, 90, 102, 55, 100, 40]
```

If you want the key and value pairings:

```
key_values =[ x for y in A.itervalues() for x in y.items()]
print key_values

[(1, 50), (2, 60), (5, 90), (10, 102), (7, 55), (10, 100), (12, 40)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to get sub-components
(rj is a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) object)

```
items=rj.items()
si = sorted(items, key=operator.itemgetter(0))

for i in si:
    t=-1
    print i[0]
    for k in i[1]:
        t+=1
        print '   ',i[1].keys()[t],':',i[1].get(k)

print len(rj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get` function on `dictionary` which returns `None` when key is not found in `dictionary`. So, if all the common keys are saved in some `set`, then iteration through it can be done:

```
A = {1:{1:50,2:60,5:90},2:{7:55,10:102},4:{10:100,12:40}}

# storing all keys in set not to save repeated keys
keys_list = {key for inner_dict in A.values() for key in list(inner_dict)}

# for each outer key
for i in A.keys():
    print(A[i]) # printing each key to check

    for j in keys_list: # looping through inner dictionary
        if A[i].get(j) is not None: # if the key is found then it is not None
            print ('Outer Key: ', i, " Inner Key: ", j, " Value: ",  A[i][j]) # now you can use A[i][j]

    print('--------------------------------------------------')
```

Output:

```
{1: 50, 2: 60, 5: 90}
Outer Key:  1  Inner Key:  1  Value:  50
Outer Key:  1  Inner Key:  2  Value:  60
Outer Key:  1  Inner Key:  5  Value:  90
--------------------------------------------------
{10: 102, 7: 55}
Outer Key:  2  Inner Key:  7  Value:  55
Outer Key:  2  Inner Key:  10  Value:  102
--------------------------------------------------
{10: 100, 12: 40}
Outer Key:  4  Inner Key:  10  Value:  100
Outer Key:  4  Inner Key:  12  Value:  40
--------------------------------------------------
```