# List to nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list as follows

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
```

I want to construct a dictionary from the above list as follows

```
{
    "item1": {
        "item2": {
            "item3": "item4"
        }
    }
}
```

The number of items in the list is dynamic. The dictionary will be a nested dictionary till it reaches the last element of the list.
Is there any way in python to do this?

Comment: Related: [Access python nested dictionary items via a list of keys](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14692690)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple one-liner:

```
a = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3','item4']
print reduce(lambda x, y: {y: x}, reversed(a))
```

For better understanding the above code can be expanded to:

```
def nest_me(x, y):
    """
    Take two arguments and return a one element dict with first
    argument as a value and second as a key
    """
    return {y: x}

a = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3','item4']
rev_a = reversed(a) # ['item4', 'item3', 'item2','item1']
print reduce(
    nest_me, # Function applied until the list is reduced to one element list
    rev_a # Iterable to be reduced
)
# {'item1': {'item2': {'item3': 'item4'}}}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use recursion:

```py
def list2dict(src_list):
    if len(src_list) > 1:
        return {src_list[0] : list2dict(src_list[1:])}
    return src_list[0]
```

Output:

```py
>>> list2dict(['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'])
{'item1': {'item2': {'item3': 'item4'}}}
```

Comment: It's a pity that @thefourtheye deleted his answer - while this solution is more natural, I must say that his had the advantage of eliminating slicing overhead - this has complexity of O(n!), his is O(n)

Comment: How does slicing make this `O(n!)`?

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`reduce()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) to access and set elements:

```
try:
    # Python 3 moved reduce to the functools module
    from functools import reduce
except ImportError:
    # Python 2 reduce is a built-in
    pass

def get_target(d, keys):
    return reduce(lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, {}), keys, d)

def set_target(d, keys, value):
    parent = get_target(d, keys[:-1])
    parent[keys[-1]] = value

result = {}
set_target(result, yourlist[:-1], yourlist[-1])
```

The `get_target()` and `set_target()` functions are re-usable on already-built nested structures, they are not limited to building a dictionary from scratch. I adapted `get_target()` from an [earlier, related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-python-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys).

Demo:

```
>>> def get_target(d, keys):
...     return reduce(lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, {}), keys, d)
... 
>>> def set_target(d, keys, value):
...     parent = get_target(d, keys[:-1])
...     parent[keys[-1]] = value
... 
>>> result = {}
>>> yourlist = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
>>> set_target(result, yourlist[:-1], yourlist[-1])
>>> result
{'item1': {'item2': {'item3': 'item4'}}}
```

Comment: Again - that solution has the advantage of complexity - recursion is O(n!), that one is O(n)

Comment: @martijn `set_target` is breaking for this case as it doesn't replace the primitive key if it's already assigned. https://imgur.com/a/TGTVoO3

Comment: @nehemiah: that's because you are mixing leaves and branch nodes here. `a -> b -> c` references a leaf node (`hello`), so you can't then turn `c` into a branch node (where `c` references another dictionary). Making the call there, to just replace `c`, is a decision you need to make for your own usecases. You can't just assume that the collision here is not an error in the application logic.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Keeping it generic is the best option here. Overriding data on a same dict key is perfectly okay behavior for Dict/Hashmap. I had to come to this implementation after countless scenarios. Here's the detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33704530/968442