# Implicit Iteration through Python dictionary elements

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, dictionary

I am trying to figure out if there is an implicit way to iterate through list elements. Example: with the list `someList = ['a','b','c']` you do not need to write a `for` loop to iterate through the list printing elements when `print(someList)` does an *implicit* iteration.

I have the following (simplified) python code:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=None
        self.y=None
        self.z=None

    def set(self, x, y , z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def get(self):
        return {'x':self.x, 'y':self.y, 'z':self.z}


class bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foos=[]
    def add(self, foo):
        self.foos.append(foo)
    def get(self):
        return {'foos':self.foos}
```

Which are initialized using

```
f = foo()
f.set(1,2,3)

g = foo()
g.set(4,5,6)


h = bar()
h.add(f)
h.add(g)
```

Then calling

```
print(f.get())
print(g.get())
print(h.get())
```

which gives

```
{'z': 3, 'x': 1, 'y': 2}
{'z': 6, 'x': 4, 'y': 5}
{'foos': [<__main__.foo object at 0x0000000003541748>, <__main__.foo object at 0x000000000358C630>]}
```

What I'm ultimately looking to do is return a JSON like structure or Nested dictionary such that the returns of the `foo.get()` method are included in the call to `bar.get()`.

I realize the array doesn't contain actual `foo` objects (only references to them).

I thought about using **iterators** like they were explained at http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html . The problem with the example is that the items to be iterated over must be defined *within* the datastructure (i.e `foo`). The problem with including the iterator in the `bar` class is that `foos` list may not be the only collection to iterate over: I could have added collection `foos2` (but did not for simplicity)

I considered the solution at [Access nested dictionary items via a list of keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-python-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys) , but the `pprint` gives me something similar to my own code. I am also not certain use of the `reduce` function would apply to my situation.

I also thought about doing **operator overloading** on the `print` function, but I'm not looking to get a string, just a data structure that easy to display but also navigate.

Is there a **easy way** or **correct way** to do this? Am I using the correct data-structure (i.e. should I be using something other than nested lists)?

I'm still new to Python so pleas be gentle.

Comment: Are you doing this just for the purposes of printing?  Or do you actually want to marshall these datatypes into a serializable format for saving somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

This returns the result of `foo.get()` in the return value of bar.get(). Is this what you are asking for?

```
class bar:
    ...
    def get(self):
        return {'foos':[foo.get() for foo in self.foos]}
```

Breaking down the `return` statement,

```
return (            # you know what this keyword does
    {               # create a dict
        'foos':     # with a key of "foos",
        [           # and a value that is a list
                    # (in this case, built from a list comprehension)
            x.get() # each element is the result of calling .get()
            for x in self.foos  # on each element of the "foos" list
        ]           # end of list comprehension
    }               # end of dict
)                   # end of return expression
```

So, the return statement returns a `dict` with exactly one key-value pair. The key is the literal string `"foos"`. The value is a list composed of the result of calling `.get()` on each of the members of the `self.foos` list. (I changed the name of the loop variable and added parentheses to make life less confusing.)

And here is the result:

```
{'x': 1, 'z': 3, 'y': 2}
{'x': 4, 'z': 6, 'y': 5}
{'foos': [{'x': 1, 'z': 3, 'y': 2}, {'x': 4, 'z': 6, 'y': 5}]}
```

A perfectly equivalent implementation of `bar.get()` could use an explicit `for` loop, as shown below. I only use the list comprehension because I find that code easier to read. If you find the below easier, use it instead.

```
def get(self):
    result = []
    for x in self.foos:
        result.append(x.get())
    return result
```

Comment: in simple terms what is this doing? I know it's a list comprehension but don't understand how it works

Comment: @Rob : YES! Its exactly what I'm looking to do. Thank you. I suppose it wasn't an issue of **impliciit** vs **explicit** iteration but an issue of **inline** vs. **non-inline** iteration. That is I didn't want to write an explicit method (or anything beyond the `get` method's `return` statement) to iterate over the `foos` collection.)

Comment: @WoodMath - I'm not sure what you mean by "inline" and "non-inline" iteration. If you mean a for loop (like `for x in foos: ...`), stay tuned. I'll add that one next.

Comment: @Rob - What I meant by inline iteration was the statement `return {'foos':[foo.get() for foo in self.foos]}`. Normally I've done `for` loops as `for x in coll: x.get()], but `return {'foos':[for foo in self.foos: foo.get()]}` is not valid python. Its one of these language specific nuances that is why I made the original post, as I need to alter how you think about common programming tasks. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing to use foo objects like lists, the best idea I can give you is to make foo iterable, this can easily be done like this:

```
class foo(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        for item in [self.x, self.y, self.z]:
            yield item
```

This will then allow you to say things like `list(foo)`

when you need to convert an iterable object to JSON. You can also define what items (and their order) need to be iterated over in place of `[self.x, self.y, self.z]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it functionally without an explicit loop, you can use map:

```
class bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foos = []

    def add(self, foo):
        self.foos.append(foo)

    def get(self):
        return {'foos': list(map(foo.get, self.foos))}
```