# Is there a clean test for a dictionary element in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, lookup

If I have an element I'm trying to get from a dictionary:
`my_dict[i]['level_1']['level_2']['my_var']`.

Is there a cleaner way than doing this to check for nulls?

```
if 'level_1' in my_dict[i]:
    if 'level_2' in my_dict[i]['level_1']:
        if 'my_var' in my_dict[i]['level_1']['level_2']:
            my_var = my_dict[i]['level_1']['level_2']['my_var']
```

Comment: You can use `dict.get` - `my_dict[i].get('level_1', {}).get('level_2', {}).get('my_var')`. It will be `None` if not found.

Comment: or a `try-except KeyError` block

Comment: Your approach here will depend entirely on what you are trying to accomplish and your desired behavior. A simple `my_var = my_dict[i]['level_1']['level_2']['my_var']` wrapped in `try-except` might be the way to go, or what jonsharpe proposed, depending on the nature of you data.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis perhaps `except (KeyError, TypeError):` which will work in case one of the entries exist but contains None instead of a dictionary.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys

Comment: https://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply define your own:

```
def get_deep(dic,*keys,default=None):
    for key in keys:
        if isinstance(dic,dict) and key in dic:
            dic = dic[key]
        else:
            return default
    return dic
```

Or if you want to test:

```
def in_deep(dic,*keys):
    for key in keys:
        if isinstance(dic,dict) and key in dic:
            dic = dic[key]
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

You can use this code with `in_deep(my_dict[i],'level1','level2','my_var')` and it will return `True` if it can indeed get that deep in the dictionary. If you want to obtain the element that deep, you can call `get_deep(my_dict[i],'level1','level2','my_var')`. `get_deep` will return the `default` parameter (by default `None`) in case it cannot reach the path.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my one-liner:

```
# returns False or the value of the end element
reduce(lambda x, y: x and y in x and x[y], list_of_keys, target_dictionary)
```

Example:

```
a = {'b': {'c': {'d': True}}}
reduce(lambda x, y: x and y in x and x[y], ['b', 'c', 'd'], a)  # True
reduce(lambda x, y: x and y in x and x[y], ['b', 'cd', 'd'], a)  # False
```

How it works: at every iteration of reduce, it checks that previouis keys were in the target dictionary (`x`). If not, it will return False because of `and` condition immediately and propagate it down the list. Then, it will check if the requested key is in the dict (`x in y`). If it is, it will pass the lower level dictionary to the lower level as `x`.

Note: the last element (a['b']['c']['d']) has to evaluate to True. If you expect False at the end, check the last level explicitly: `'d' in reduce(...)`