# remove element in nested dict by list of keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary structure like so:

```
dataDict = {
"a":{
    "r": 1,
    "s": 2,
    "t": 3
    },
"b":{
    "u": 1,
    "v": {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 2,
        "z": 3
    },
    "w": 3
    }
}
```

with a list of keys:

```
maplist = ["b", "v", "y"]
```

I want to remove the item in the dict that the maplist is pointing to. Any suggestions?

Comment: suggestions: don't remove items, build a new dict; and simply recursively traverse the `dataDict`. Coding efforts from the question asker are appreicated

Comment: I am not able to understand exact problem. Can you write expected result?

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way. In future, please refer to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys) where you found this data.

`getFromDict` function [courtesy of @MartijnPieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14692747/9209546).

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

def getFromDict(dataDict, mapList):
    return reduce(operator.getitem, mapList[:-1], dataDict)

maplist = ["b", "v", "y"]

del getFromDict(dataDict, maplist)[maplist[-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `del` after accessing:

```
del dataDict[maplist[0]][maplist[1]][maplist[2]]
```

which gives:

```
dataDict = {
"a":{
    "r": 1,
    "s": 2,
    "t": 3
    },
"b":{
    "u": 1,
    "v": {
        "x": 1,
        "z": 3
    },
    "w": 3
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for a list of length 3, but will not work for arbitrary length lists. Relevant given dictionary structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
for k in maplist:
    if k in dataDict:
        del dataDict[k]
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'s': 2, 'r': 1, 't': 3}}
```

Comment: this will only work for first level keys in dictionary and will not work for nested dictionaries, try your code by with `maplist = ['v', 'y']`

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that, let me modify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
maplist = ["b", "v", "y"]
dataDict = {'a': {'s': 2, 'r': 1, 't': 3}, 'b': {'u': 1, 'w': 3, 'v': {'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}}}  
def remove_keys(d):
  return {a:remove_keys(b) if isinstance(b, dict) else b for a, b in d.items() if a not in maplist}

final_result = remove_keys(dataDict)
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'s': 2, 'r': 1, 't': 3}}
```