# Navigating a nested dictionary using a deque

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like so:

```
{
    a: {
        b: {
            c: "Hello World!"
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a deque like so:

```
deque(["a", "b", "c"])
```

I would like to print `Hello World!` using the two data structures above - how can this be done?

Comment: What have you attempted? Is something in particular challenging you?

Comment: If you have `my_dict = {...}`, you can do `mydict['a']` to index the first level of nesting.

Comment: `while y: x = x[y.popleft()]`

Comment: Not deque specific but `functools.reduce(operator.getitem, deq, d)` is a nice way. [Related (possible duplicate) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `x` is your dictionary, and `y` is your deque:

```
while y:
    x = x[y.popleft()]
```

`x` is now:

```
'Hello World!'
```

There are easier ways to accomplish this, like as @miradulo mentioned:

```
functools.reduce(operator.getitem, y, x)
```

But this makes use of `popleft()` which is a deque operation.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and it's only 2 lines - thanks a lot.

Comment: This also exhausts the deque, so you know you are finished.

Answer (score 4):

I dont know why you want to this but this may help:

```
 for i in deque(['a','b','c']):
     d= d[i]
 > d
 Hello World!
```

It only works if the dict has those keys, you can improve code as much as you can. 
one more think is that the dictionary should have keys with `'` like `'a'`.