# Build a tree from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to build a dict in form of a tree from a list.
The first keys are the last elements of the list.

```
current = [['A1'], ['B1', 'A1'], ['B2', 'A1'], ['C1', 'B2', 'A1'], ['D2', 'C1', 'B2', 'A1'], ['D1', 'C1', 'B2', 'A1'], ['A2']]

expected = {
  'A1': {
    'B1': None,
    'B2': {
      'C1': {
        'D1': None,
        'D2': None
      },
    },
  },
  'A2': None
}
```

I have tried something with default dict, but no success in make it recursively, and i don't know if it's the correct way.

```
result = defaultdict(list)
for e in current:
    result[e[-1]].append(e)
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what is the problem with it?

Comment: I have tried some solutions with defaultdict, but no success. I have no idea how to convert this list to that dict

Comment: There is no question. Having no idea is not a question. NB: the question should be specific. There are lots of resources and tutorials, so surely you can make a start. Tell us where you bump into an issue.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] of that, then

Comment: Why the expected is wrong? The question is how to transform one input in specific form in one output. Why is it not minimal , complete and verifiable?

Comment: How can we know whether what you tell us is "expected" is wrong? A task ("transforming") is not a question.

Comment: Expected is the result that I want from that input, someone said that maybe it was wrong, I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe the correct word is convert. How to convert that list into that dict?

Comment: @GabrielNoth StackOverflow is not intended to be a code writing sevice. We are happy to help, but please show some effort from your part (which include reading about the subject and trying a few things yoursefl).

Comment: "Someone said that maybe it was wrong, I don't know why": this really needs more explanation? If you don't know what is expected, then how should we know?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear with the question, but  Lordfirespeed understood this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't have the *None* which you wanted, instead providing empty *dict* objects. However, it does form the expected tree from the list provided:

```
current = [['A1'], ['B1', 'A1'], ['B2', 'A1'], ['C1', 'B2', 'A1'], ['D2', 'C1', 'B2', 'A1'], ['D1', 'C1', 'B2', 'A1'], ['A2']]
tree = {}

for item in current:
    currentdict = tree
    for key in item[::-1]:
        if key not in currentdict.keys():
            currentdict[key] = {}
        currentdict = currentdict[key]

expected = {
  'A1': {
    'B1': {},
    'B2': {
      'C1': {
        'D1': {},
        'D2': {}
      },
    },
  },
  'A2': {}
}

print(tree == expected)  # True
```

Comment: ".keys()" is not necessary in "if key not in currentdict.keys():", correct?

Comment: @GabrielNoth No, it's not necessary, as _key in dict_ will read the dict as a list of keys - however it is more concise.

Comment: @Lordfirespeed it's *less* concise, it's literally more characters

Comment: @jonrsharpe fair point. I'll often take comprehensive and legible over concise code though.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way to do it.

First we will borrow methods from --> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14692747/6817835)

```
import pprint
from operator import getitem
from functools import reduce

def getdict(dict_, mappings):
    return reduce(getitem, mappings, dict_)

def setdict(dict_, mappings):
    getdict(dict_, mappings[:-1])[mappings[-1]] = dict()

d = dict()

for cur in current:
    c = cur[::-1]
    setdict(d, c)

pprint.pprint(d)

{'A1': {'B1': {}, 'B2': {'C1': {'D1': {}, 'D2': {}}}}, 'A2': {}}
```