# Access nested dictionary through a variable

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following setup: a function returns a dictionary with N timelines of equal size (100k points). The dictionary returns looks like:

```
timelines = dict()
timelines["Name1"] = dict()
timelines["Name1"]["Name2"] = dict()
timelines["Name1"]["Name3"] = dict()
timelines["Name1"]["Name2"]["a"] = # List of 100k points
timelines["Name1"]["Name2"]["b"] = # List of 100k points
timelines["Name1"]["Name2"]["c"] = # List of 100k points
timelines["Name1"]["Name3"]["b"] = # List of 100k points
timelines["Name1"]["Name2"]["c"] = # List of 100k points
timelines["Name1"]["a"] = # List of 100k points
timelines["Name1"]["b"] = # List of 100k points
timelines["Name2"] # and so on.
```

As you might have understood, the timelines (list of points) are not always stored in the same level. Sometimes I can access it with 1 key, sometimes with 2, sometimes with 5.
Those keys will give me the labels for the plot and are necessary. My plan was to pass to the plot function a tuple of the keys.

Example:

```
T = ("Name1", "Name2", "b") 
# Will allow me to access the timeline:
timelines["Name1"]["Name2"]["b"]
# by doing:
timelines[T[0]][T[1]][T[2]]
```

In the example above, I wrote the dictionary path myself (`[T[0]][T[1]][T[2]]`), however how can I acess the right timeline with a tuple T of unknown size? How can I unpack the tuple into a dictionary path?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you access your dict many times, it may be beneficial to flatten it and compressing the keys to have easier access later. Read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14692747/9225671) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6027615/9225671).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would actually do it like this, this will be the fastest method more than likely

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem

path = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'a']

reduce(getitem, path, dictionary)
```

`Lambda` calls can become expensive especially as data grows, not to mention `getitem` will be faster than any other method listed here because it's implemented purely in `C`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

```
from functools import reduce

timelines = dict()
timelines["Name1"] = dict()
timelines["Name1"]["Name2"] = dict()
timelines["Name1"]["Name2"]["b"] = 'my data'

T = ("Name1", "Name2", "b") 

data = reduce(lambda d, key: d[key], T, timelines)

print(data)
# my data
```

The initial value is your `timeline` dict. Reduce iterates on your `T` tuple, and at each iteration, calls the lambda function. The lambda takes two arguments: the first one is the accumulated value, in this case the current dict `d`, and the second one is the key it got from the tuple during this iteration. The lambda returns `d[key]`, which becomes the new accumulated value for the next iteration.

Comment: Works great. Could you explain a bit what it does? I don't get this lambda statement.

Comment: it's a better approach to do `reduce(getitem, [list_of_keys], input_dict)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use a recursive approach

```
def access_my_dict(my_dict, tuple_keys):
    value = my_dict[tuple_keys[0]]
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        return access_my_dict(value, tuple_keys[0:])
    return value
```

Answer (score 1):

Traverse the data structure like this:

```
timelines = dict()
timelines["Name1"] = dict()
timelines["Name2"] = dict()
timelines["Name1"]["Name2"] = dict()
timelines["Name1"]["Name3"] = dict()
timelines["Name1"]["Name2"]["a"] = []  # List of 100k points
timelines["Name1"]["Name2"]["b"] = [12, 67, 45]  # List of 100k points
timelines["Name1"]["Name2"]["c"] = [12, 45]  # List of 100k points
timelines["Name1"]["Name3"]["b"] = []  # List of 100k points
timelines["Name1"]["Name2"]["c"] = []  # List of 100k points
timelines["Name1"]["a"] = []  # List of 100k points
timelines["Name1"]["b"] = []  # List of 100k points
timelines["Name2"]["Name23"] = dict()
timelines["Name2"]["Name23"]["Z"] = []  # and so on.


def get_time_line(path):
    data = timelines
    for path_element in path:
        data = data[path_element]
    return data

path = ("Name1", "Name2", "b")
print(get_time_line(path))
```

Output:

```
[12, 67, 45]
```