# How to update values in json via long path?

Tags: python, json, path

I can't find any info on how can I update original JSON message values with complex paths with different depths.

I tried the `jsonpath` lib, but it's documentation is all about getting values, and not setting them.

For example I have the following JSON:

```
{"very":{"long":{"path":{"A":"1"}}},"other":{"path":{"even":{"deeper":{"B":"2"}}}}}
```

Two paths can be specified outside a function.
This one maps to `"1"`:

```
very.long.path.A
```

And this one to `"2"`:

```
other.path.even.deeper.B
```

`jsonpath` can extract values from provided paths, but my goal is to modify them.

Something that allows the following would be ideal :

```
old_json = '{"very":{"long":{"path":{"A":"1"}}},"other":{"path":{"even":{"deeper":{"B":"2"}}}}}'
path = "other.path.even.deeper.B"
value = "100500"
new_json = jsonparser.update_value(old_json, path, value)
```

Is there a library that can provide such functionalities ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Read

To decode json you can use the builtin [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library. It is very easy to use. It transfroms json data into valid python objects. [See Encoders and decoders](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders)

In your case it would be mainly a dict. To Access Elements in a dict see [python dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

### Update

Now you Need to split your path into seperate keys `keys = path.split(".")` and iterate to the last one.

```
element = json_decoded_root
for key in keys[:-1]:
    element = element.setdefault(key, {})
element[keys[-1]] = new_value
```

### Write back

```
json.dump(file, data) # Writing to file
```

or

```
new_json = json.dumps(data) # Writing in string
```

### Extra: Why you don't lose data

I don't know if I understand you, but this example Shows why you don't lose data when you change a value in a dict.

```
>>> example = {"A" : 20, "B": 10}
>>> example["A"] = 30
>>> example
{'A': 30, 'B': 10}
```

You can 'lose' data when you overwrite it. e.g.

```
>>> example = {"A" : {"C": 10}, "B": 10}
>>> example["A"] = 30
>>> example
{'A': 30, 'B': 10}
```

Here you 'lost' The dict that conatains the "C" key

Comment: how thats hepls to **set** new value in original json? my first idea was the same, but this solution isn't resolve my issue.

Comment: You can then use [json.dump or json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html?highlight=json#json.dumps) to update the json in the file or string

Comment: i mean this works only with simple json. if i had {"a":"1"} that will work. but when path is not thiat simple you can't set it through element[keys[-1]].

Comment: and more than that json can contains several fields at the end of the node. we can't lose them

Comment: Because of this you update the element object in the for Loop till the end of the path. I took parts of my answer from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36929668/8411228

Comment: You dont lose data, except you overwrite it with other data. I suggest you to try it with a very simple example and debug it. You only Need to understand how dicts work. Try to Experiment with them first

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. I still didn't get how i don't lose my other values, but i know where to dig.

Comment: I added a short example why you don't lose data. Hopefully it helps. otherwise you are welcome to ask again