# How to access nested field in JSON with address given in Python

Tags: python, json

What is the simplest way to access a field in json data if entire key-address is given in a list.

E.g., Given "data" a json object and `["context", "body", "gk"]` as the list of keys, i.e.

```
resultant value = data["context"]["body"]["gk"]
```

In this, list of keys can be of any length.

Is there any simpler approach to this?

```
target = json.loads(data)
for elem in key_list:
    target = target[elem]
print target
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code does **not** do what you think it does, so you are looking for a working way, not a "simpler" way. Also, please see [ask] and provide reproducible examples.

Comment: Please do add some data sample which we can try out and check

Comment: Edited, not it's working. sample: "{'meta': {u'central': {u'request_id': u'612988c6-2dc2hgke', u'collected_at': 1570273182061}}}"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access nested dictionary items via a list of keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys)

Comment: I don't see any problem to your code

Comment: code is working well, but any one liner possible??

Answer (score 1):

Hah, good question! You need to repeatedly apply a function (`dict.get`), and the tool for this is `reduce`. Like this:

```
path = ["context", "body", "gk"]
data = {"context": { "body": {"gk": 42 }}}

from functools import reduce
print(reduce(dict.get, path, data))
# output: 42
```

If you have a dict-like object that might or might not have overridden the `get` method, you can use *its* `get` method instead of `dict.get`, like this:

```
reduce(type(data).get, path, data)
```