# Appending (not replacing) items in a nested dictionary via a list of keys

Tags: python, dictionary

This is a follow up to following question on SO:

[Access nested dictionary items via a list of keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys)

All the solutions given in the above link **allows to replace/create a value** of the nested dict via a list of keys. **But my requirement is to append (update) another dict to value.**

If my dict is as follows:

```
dataDict = {
    "a":{
        "r": 1,
        "s": 2,
        "t": 3
        },
    "b":{
        "u": 1,
        "v": {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 2,
            "z": 3
        },
        "w": 3
        }
}
```

And my list of keys is as follows:

```
maplist = ["b", "v"]
```

How can I append another dict, say `"somevalue": {}` to the `dataDict['b']['v']` using my maplist?

So, after appending new dataDict would look as follows:

```
dataDict = {
        "a":{
            "r": 1,
            "s": 2,
            "t": 3
            },
        "b":{
            "u": 1,
            "v": {
                "x": 1,
                "y": 2,
                "z": 3,
                "somevalue": {}
            },
            "w": 3
            }
    }
```

The solutions on the aforementioned SO link changes/creates the value like this:

```
dataDict[mapList[-1]] = value
```

But we can't call the dict's update function like `dataDict[mapList[-1]].update()`.

Checked all of SO and Google, but no luck. Could someone please provide some help with this. Thanks!

Comment: `dataDict['a']['b']` is a KeyError. What is your expected output?

Comment: Can you provide sample output?

Comment: Just updated my question with sample output and fixed the KeyError

Comment: @VivekSingh Check my answer does it solve now?

Comment: @ Ch3steR Hard luck bro! My reputation less than 125, so my vote doesn't show up publicly :)

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
def set_item(this_dict, maplist, key, value):
    for k in maplist:
        if k not in this_dict:
            this_dict[k] = {}
        this_dict = this_dict[k]

    this_dict[key] = value

dataDict = {
    "a":{
        "r": 1,
        "s": 2,
        "t": 3
        },
    "b":{
        "u": 1,
        "v": {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 2,
            "z": 3
        },
        "w": 3
        }
}

maplist = ["b", "v"]
new_key = "somevalue"
new_value = {}

set_item(dataDict, maplist, new_key, new_value)

print(dataDict)
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'r': 1, 's': 2, 't': 3}, 'b': {'u': 1, 'v': {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3, 'somevalue': {}}, 'w': 3}}
```

Comment: pylint would say that `not x in y` should be written as `x not in y`

Comment: also `k in some_dict.keys()` can be written simply as `k in some_dict`.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I was searching for something more concise, but something is better than nothing, so I'm happy with this :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [setdefault()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault) method.

```
>>>dataDict['b']['v'].setdefault('something',{})
>>>print(dataDict)
{'a': {'r': 1, 's': 2, 't': 3}, 
'b': {'u': 1, 'v': {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3, 'something': {}}, 
'w': 3}}
```

The above is the idea of how it works. Make a function for the above.

```
def set_new_key(d:dict,x:list,y:str):
    for key in x:
        d=d[key]
    d.setdefault(y,{})

dataDict = {
    "a":{
        "r": 1,
        "s": 2,
        "t": 3
        },
    "b":{
        "u": 1,
        "v": {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 2,
            "z": 3
        },
        "w": 3
        }
}

mapList=['b','v']
set_new_key(dataDict,mapList,'something')
print(dataDict)
print()
set_new_key(dataDict,['a'],'another')
print(dataDict)
print()
set_new_key(dataDict,['b','v','something'],'inside something')
print(dataDict)
```

---

output:

```
{'a': {'r': 1, 's': 2, 't': 3}, 'b': {'u': 1, 'v': {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3, 'something': {}}, 'w': 3}}

{'a': {'r': 1, 's': 2, 't': 3, 'another': {}}, 'b': {'u': 1, 'v': {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3, 'something': {}}, 'w': 3}}

{'a': {'r': 1, 's': 2, 't': 3, 'another': {}}, 'b': {'u': 1, 'v': {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3, 'something': {'inside something': {}}}, 'w': 3}}
```

Comment: Thanks Ch3steR! But this is not useful for my scenario because I need to update the dict dynamically using the list of keys in another function.

Comment: @VivekSingh check the edited answer. btw it was dynamic from the start.