# How to get a python dict value by using in his key in a dict within other dicts

Tags: python

Some one know if its possible to get a dict inside a dict by using their keys as strings... Sorry for the bad explation i think the code would be more clear... don't know how to properly say this

```
s={"framework": {"challenger": {
    "logo.qvg": "50c137c8199d0a807bc31b5c384e67d6c1c0837061bd7d39ed15943b"}}}

possible_folders=["tractor","svg","framework","common",'framework["challenger"]']

print(s['framework']['challenger'])  # this line is working

print(s[possible_folders[-1]])   # here im getting keyerror-> due to the string...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is a way to access nested dicts by a sequence of keys.  There are many ways to do this.  One I like is to define a simple function like:

```
def nested_get(d, *keys, *, default=None):
    for k in keys:
        try:
            d = d[k]
        except KeyError:
            return default

    return d
```

Then use a tuple like `keys = ('framework', 'challenger')`:

```
nested_get(d, *keys)
```

Comment: If passing tuples isn't very fancy, you can try to pass a single string like `"framework/challenger"`, split it inside the function by `/` and access the element similarly as @Iguananaut suggested. Though of course need to pay attention not to use `/` as a part of the key, only as a delimiter

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible. `s` is a `dict` with a single key, `"framework"`. There is no way to index `s` to get something deeper inside one of `s`'s values.

You can write a *function* that takes a list of keys and iteratively digs into the `dict`, however. ([Iguananaut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68194745/1126841) does this with better error handling.)

```
def chain_lookup(s, *keys):
    d = s
    for key in keys:
        d = d[key]
    return d


result = chain_lookup(s, "framework", "challenger")
# result == {"logo.qvg": "..."}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `eval()` function like:

```
s={"framework": {"challenger": {
    "logo.qvg": "50c137c8199d0a807bc31b5c384e67d6c1c0837061bd7d39ed15943b"}}}

possible_folders=["tractor","svg","framework","common",'framework["challenger"]']


def get_entry(d, k):
    
    eval_string = "d" +"".join([".get('" + i.replace('"',"").replace("[","").replace("]","") + "')" for i in k.split("[")])
    return eval(eval_string)
```

```
get_entry(s,possible_folders[-1])
Out[32]: {'logo.qvg': '50c137c8199d0a807bc31b5c384e67d6c1c0837061bd7d39ed15943b'}
```

I am not saying I would recommend it, but it is the only solution that works with the String Syntax in your questions. The other answers are better, however require a change in your list

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the above answers, because they're how you do it in a good programming way. Although I have a quick fix to make your exact command work, but it is NOT a good programming way, since it uses hardcoding and also eval function.

In the first line, you are accessing with print(s['framework']['challenger']), but in second line, you are accessing like s['framework["challenger"]' (see the brackets).

You can change the possible folders from

`possible_folders=["tractor","svg","framework","common",'framework["challenger"]']`

to

```
possible_folders=["tractor","svg","framework","common",'["framework"]["challenger"]']
eval("s"+possible_folders[-1])
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all I strongly suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys) - I would go that way.
Having said that, below you will find the non-responsible way (using `eval`) of achieving this. Again, strongly suggest going [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys) way.

```
possible_folders=["tractor","svg","framework","common","['framework']['challenger']"]
print(eval('s'+possible_folders[-1]))
```