# How can I use a string representing a path of dict key as a dict key in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have strings that represent JSON key paths. I would like to use those to go get the actual value of that path inside of my nested JSON data, like so:

```py
path_a = "['id']"
path_b = "['users'][0]['address']['street']"
path_c = "['houses'][2]['block'][0]['is_viable']"

print(json_data[path_a])
print(json_data[path_b])
print(json_data[path_c])
```

As you guessed, the print returns an error:

```
KeyError: "['id']"
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I gave a few examples of paths here but the main thing about my code is that I cannot know in advance how many "keys" will be in a path, so I cannot simply type `print(json_data[path[0]][path[1]][path[2]][path[3]][path[4]])`.

Comment: Yes, there's a way to achieve it. You need to parse the string to something more usable, then apply e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/14692690/3001761.

Comment: @Pxmme for example in 1st print you need to print the value with key id i e. json_data['id'] ? Is my understanding right?

Comment: Hey @jonrsharpe, thanks, this worked!! Thanks a lot. How can I "mark" this issue as "Resolved"? I'm new here, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get a given data from a dictionary with position provided as a list
def getFromDict(dataDict, mapList):    
    for k in mapList: dataDict = dataDict[k]
    return dataDict

# Set a given data in a dictionary with position provided as a list
def setInDict(dataDict, mapList, value): 
    for k in mapList[:-1]: dataDict = dataDict[k]
    dataDict[mapList[-1]] = value
```

Those functions worked like a charm with what I was trying to do!