# Get Folders name into JSON specific format

Tags: python, json, data-structures, tree

Trying to get folders name (without file names) from a directory and covert them into JSON format. So after 4 iteration of the folders, i will try to get userinput from the user.
My current working code is:

```
import glob
import json
import io

in0  = input("Enter Userinput0:\n")
in1  = input("Enter Userinput1:\n") 
in2  = input("Enter Userinput2:\n")
in3  = input("Enter Userinput3:\n")
name = "somename"

def path_to_dict(path):

data = {os.path.basename(path): {}}
if os.path.isdir(path):
count = 0
    for x in os.listdir(path):
        data[os.path.basename(path)] =[path_to_dict(os.path.join(path,x))]
    count += 1
    if count == 4:
        break
    return data
path_to_dict('some path')
d = {"Userinput0": in0}
d[name] = {data: {"Userinput1": in1,"Userinput2": in2,"Userinput3": in3, }}
j = json.dumps(d, indent=5)
print (j)
```

Output for the above code:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

My tree structure:

```
|-Folder1
|--Subfolder       
|---Subfolder
|----Subfolder 
|-----Subfolder
```

Output JSON format i am trying to get:

```
{
  "Userinput0": "x.x", 
  "Somename": {
    "Folder1": {
      "subfolder": {
         "subfolder": {
            "subfolder": {
                "subfolder": {
                    "Userinput1": "x",
                    "Userinput2": "Y",
                    "Userinput3": Z
                }
            }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

I have edited my question and current code. Still i am not able to attain desired output
So could anyone please help me to achieve the output.

Comment: It is unclear how you get to the result that those `Userinput` values should be set at that exact nested path. It's somewhat trivial to build a dict structure for folder paths, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/14692690/476. But you could easily have the folders `['/foo/bar/', '/foo/baz/']`. Now what? Where do the `Userinput`s go? What's the expected result?

Comment: @deceze I have updated my question. As per my output structure, i should not get ['folder name'],  and **userinput** values should be nested at the exact path as per the output format

Comment: And the question is: how do you programatically determine "the exact path as per the output format"?! If you get an arbitrarily nested set of arbitrary folders from `glob`, *where* do you put the user inputs?!

Comment: As per my code, i have set the userinputs in a path, i have to traverse through the folders name in specific path `d[name] = {data: {"Userinput1": in1,"Userinput2": in2,"Userinput3": in3, }}` here userinputs are already in path, in place of **data** i am trying to pull names of the folders

Comment: You have a bunch of folders on disk. You want to create a JSON structure that represents those folders. E.g. if you have the folders `foo/bar/baz/`, you want `{'foo': {'bar': {'baz': {}}}}`, correct? Now, how do you determine that the user inputs should be at `{'foo': {'bar': {'baz': {'Userinput1': ...}}}}`? Because the folders on your disk that you get through `glob` might also lead to `{'foo': {}, 'bar': {'baz': {}}}`! Now what?

Comment: Whatever you said as Eg is correct. According to my folder structure, e.g. `foo/bar/baz/quz`  so exactly after 4th subfolder, i am trying to put the user inputs values. So if we use `glob` it will lead to `{'foo': {}, 'bar': {'baz': {}}}`. so do we have any alternate option then

Comment: How do you determine "4th subfolder"? Is "4" a hardcoded number? Can this rule be expressed any other way? And yes, what alternatives *do* you have?! It's *your* rules that you're making up here, you need to be able to express them clearly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243617/discussion-between-anonymous-and-deceze).

Comment: @Anonymous since the question is still lacking clarity, add the clarified details in the question rather than continuing them on chat imo

Comment: @AbhinavMathur i have edited my question. Can you please have a look at it

Comment: Just copy and paste your example code, could you make it run?

Answer (score 0):

def path_to_dict(path):

```
data = {os.path.basename(path): {
                "Userinput1": in1,
                "Userinput2": in2,
                "Userinput3": in3,
            }}
if os.path.isdir(path):
    count = 0
    for x in os.listdir(path):
        data[os.path.basename(path)] =path_to_dict(os.path.join(path,x))
        count += 1
        if count == 4:
            break
    
    return data
```

print(path_to_dict)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).