# Is there a way to make a string work as a list index?

Tags: python, string, list

Let's say I've got a string mystr = "mylist[0][1]" and a list called mylist which contains many words. I want to print the second letter of a first word in my list (as my string suggests). How can I do this? When I try to use print(mystr) it obviously prints mylist[0][1] instead of my letter.

Comment: Does it have to be from a string? Could you use a list of indexes like `[0, 1]`?

Comment: `print(eval(mystr))` will do what you want, but `eval()` is dangerous because it can execute arbitrary code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys for a general way to do this with lists and dictionaries and a list of indexes/keys.

Comment: What's the background of this question? How come you want to do this?

Comment: Well, at first I get a long string consisting of double indexes in form of long_str = "[1][2] [3][4] [5][6]" and also o list (let's call it mylist) with words which is supposed to work as a decryption key. Then I make a list of indexes out of long_str and for every double_index, I want to print mylist[double_index].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use something like this approach:

```
mystr = "mylist[0][1]"
splited = mystr.split('[')
i = int(splited[1].replace(']', ''))
j = int(splited[2].replace(']', ''))
print(mylist[i][j])
```

Comment: I suspect he wants something more general, so it can handle an arbitrary number of indexes.

Comment: I've only got double indexes, so Parazok's method works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eval` function to interpret a string as code, but I don't recommend it.

```py
print(eval(mystr))
```

There are many reasons why this is a bad idea:

1. It is very slow. The Python interpreter has to parse the string, analyze it and interpret it at this point in the program. If it's in a loop, it has to do all the work each time through the loop.
2. It may be a security risk for code injection. If any part of the string comes from an external input, an attacker could send it some undesirable code that your program would then execute.

Comment: You don't need the concatenation. `print(eval(mystr))`. You're confusing it with `exec()`.

Comment: @Barmar My version with eval("print...") would work too because print() is a valid Python expression and can be eval'ed, but I agree that your suggestion is simpler, edited.

Comment: I know it works. "don't need" means you're doing extra, unnecessary work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of evaluating the string containing an object identifier you can try to access to it via the `globals()` dictionary. This process is a bit tedious and can be done more rigorously, for example, using a regular expression.

```
mylist = [[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 8]]

mystr = "mylist[0][1]"

key, coord1, coord2 = mystr.split('[')
# remove last character, ]
coord1 = int(coord1[:-1])
coord2 = int(coord2[:-1])

l = globals()[key][coord1][coord2]
print(l)
```