# Navigate in Python Dict from Variable

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm trying to navigate a dict in python using a variable as key path, but getting key error:

```
testeobj = {'a': 'b', 'c': {'d': {'e':'f'}}}
for k, v in testeobj.items():
    print(f"k:{k}, v:{v}") #OK
nav = "['c']['d']"
print(testeobj[nav]) # testeobj['c']['d'] works good
```

`KeyError: "['c']['d']"`

There's any way to do this ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What exactly are you trying to do with ```nav```?

Comment: You are not going to be able to do this with a string like `"['c']['d']"` — python just thinks this is a string and will try to use is as a key like any other string. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692690/access-nested-dictionary-items-via-a-list-of-keys) for some ideas on how you might do this with a list like `['c', 'd']`.

Answer (score 1):

Make `nav` a list of keys, and then you can iterate over it to navigate the dictionary:

```
testeobj = {'a': 'b', 'c': {'d': {'e':'f'}}}
nav = ['c', 'd']
o = testeobj
for key in nav:
    o = o[key]
print(o)  # {'e': 'f'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right, you can't treat a string (`"['c']['d']"`) as Python code like that. There's no native syntax to support something like that, but if you store the path in a list or tuple, like:

```
nav = ('c', 'd')
```

Then we can use a loop to retrieve the desired value:

```
testobj = {'a': 'b', 'c': {'d': {'e':'f'}}}
for k, v in testobj.items():
    print(f"k:{k}, v:{v}") #OK
nav = ('c', 'd')

mark = testobj
for k in nav:
    mark = mark[k]

print(f'path {nav}: {mark}')
```

Which produces:

```
k:a, v:b
k:c, v:{'d': {'e': 'f'}}
path ('c', 'd'): {'e': 'f'}
```

There are also modules such as [jmespath](https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/) and others that allow you to use dot notation to navigate python objects:

```
import jmespath


testobj = {'a': 'b', 'c': {'d': {'e':'f'}}}
for k, v in testobj.items():
    print(f"k:{k}, v:{v}") #OK
nav = 'c.d'
mark = jmespath.search(nav, testobj)
print(f'path {nav}: {mark}')
```

Which produces:

```
k:a, v:b
k:c, v:{'d': {'e': 'f'}}
path c.d: {'e': 'f'}
```

Or, using `/` delimited paths in [jsonpointer](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpointer/):

```
import jsonpointer


testobj = {'a': 'b', 'c': {'d': {'e':'f'}}}
for k, v in testobj.items():
    print(f"k:{k}, v:{v}") #OK
nav = '/c/d'
mark = jsonpointer.resolve_pointer(testobj, nav)
print(f'path {nav}: {mark}')
```

Which produces:

```
k:a, v:b
k:c, v:{'d': {'e': 'f'}}
path /c/d: {'e': 'f'}
```