# Efficient access of nested dictionaries from a list of keys

Tags: python

I would like to be able to access a nested dictionary from a list of keys.
For example, if

```py
d = {
    'a': {
        'b': {
            'c': 1
        },
        'd': 2
    }
}
```

To access `c` I need the keys `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'` and I can do it easily as `d['a']['b']['c']`. However, the value for key `'d'` is one level up w.r.t. `'c'` so I need one pair of square brackets `[]` less.

Of course, I can write a function

```py
def access(d: Dict, keys: List[str]):
    cur_dict = d
    for key in keys:
        cur_dict = cur_dict[key]
    return cur_dict
```

But I was wondering if there is any built-in method or library that does it more efficiently.

Comment: What does "efficiently" mean in this context? If it means "fast" then this seems fairly fast to me. If you want some alternate way to filter/read a dictionary then maybe you want to look at https://pypi.org/project/jmespath/ or alternatives like it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14692747/198633