# Create multidimensional dictionary from list elements

Tags: python

I have list of elements like `a=[0,1,2,3]`, I want to convert these list elements into multidimensional dictionary `a[0][1][2][3]` is it possible using python.

i.e input `a=[0,1,2,3]` and desired output `a[0][1][2][3]`

I have a function that call the `a[0] if list contains a=[0]`, `a[0][1] if list contains a=[0,1]` and `a[0][1][2] if list contains a=[0,1,2]` elements.
I have elements of the list but not able to call my function according to my need.

I don't want to use numpy package, I there any easy method?

Comment: I don't think the problem is well defined. What's the value of a[0][1][2][3]? None?

Comment: Do you want to fill a dict or just access an item in a nested dict given a sequence of keys? If the latter, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14692690/1258041).

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate; if the linked question does not address your problem, then please clarify the difference by editing the question, and it will be reopened.

Comment: For setting values in a dict, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/13687924/1258041

Comment: I have a function which call a[0] then after some time it call a[0][1] and a[0][1][2] depending upon the list element a=[0],a=[0,1] and a=[0,1,2].

Comment: @LevLevitsky the solution that your are offering is totally different from my problem and this question is not duplicate, kindly check my problem again.

Comment: @user199354 try this call: nested_set(d, [0,1,2,3], {}) . Using the function of the linked question you can access like you want d[0][1][2][3]

Comment: Please [edit] the question by clarifying exactly what you need. From your question and comments, it's hard to understand what you already have and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @LevLevitsky I have edit the question hopefully I make better sense now.

Comment: Maybe include a specific example? I still don't see the difference.