# How do I insert new items in a blank dictionary in Python 3?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, key-value

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
mydict = {'HEALTH': {'NumberOfTimes': 2, 'Score': 12},
 'branch': {'NumberOfTimes': 4, 'Score': 34},
 'transfer': {'NumberOfTimes': 1, 'Score': 5},
 'deal': {'NumberOfTimes': 1, 'Score': 10}}
```

I want to divide the `Score` by `NumberOfTimes` for each key in `mydict`, and save it in either a list or another dictionary. The goal is to have the following:

```
newdict = {word:'HEALTH', 'AvgScore': 6},
 {word:'branch': 4, 'AvgScore': 8.5},
 {word:'transfer', 'AvgScore': 5},
 {word:'deal', 'AvgScore': 10}}
```

My code for the latter is as follows:

```
newdict = {}
for k, v in mydict.items():
    newdict[k]['AvgScore'] = v['Score']/v['NumberOfTimes']
```

But this gives the error `KeyError: 'HEALTH'`.

I tried the following as well:

```
from collections import defaultdict
newdict = defaultdict(dict)

for k, v in mydict.items():
    newdict[k]['AvgScore'] = v['Score']/v['NumberOfTimes']
```

Here I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-237-d6ecaf92029c> in <module>()
      4 # newdict = {}
      5 for k, v in mydict.items():
----> 6     newdict[k]['AvgScore'] = v['Score']/v['NumberOfTimes']
      7 
      8 #sorted(newdict.items())

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How do I add the key-value pairs into a new dictionary?

Comment: replace `for k, v in word_vec.items():` with `for k, v in mydict.items():`

Comment: for first error `KeyError: 'HEALTH'`, try to use `update` to add new key, and if you have nested dicts, you should add all levels by `youdict.update`.

Comment: The problem is your try to set a nested dict like `newdict[k]['AvgScore']`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687924/setting-a-value-in-a-nested-python-dictionary-given-a-list-of-indices-and-value) for ways to achieve that kind of behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple iteration.

**Demo:**

```
mydict = {'HEALTH': {'NumberOfTimes': 2, 'Score': 12},
 'branch': {'NumberOfTimes': 4, 'Score': 34},
 'transfer': {'NumberOfTimes': 1, 'Score': 5},
 'deal': {'NumberOfTimes': 1, 'Score': 10}}

newdict = {}
for k, v in mydict.items():
    newdict[k] = {"word": k, 'AvgScore': v['Score']/v['NumberOfTimes']}
print(newdict.values())
```

**Output:**

```
[{'word': 'transfer', 'AvgScore': 5}, {'word': 'HEALTH', 'AvgScore': 6}, {'word': 'branch', 'AvgScore': 8}, {'word': 'deal', 'AvgScore': 10}]
```

Comment: In my actual dictionary (I only showed the first 4 key-value pairs in it, but it has some thousands), I get the following error with your code: `TypeError: string indices must be integers` on the line `word_vec_avg[k] = {"word": k, 'AvgScore': v['Score']/v['NumberOfTimes']}`

Comment: Yes. In fact, when I just copy the first 4 entries in `mydict` as here, there's no error. The error only comes when taking the full dictionary.

Comment: Looks like you have a list in your dict. Please check your dict values

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mydict = {'HEALTH': {'NumberOfTimes': 2, 'Score': 12},
 'branch': {'NumberOfTimes': 4, 'Score': 34},
 'transfer': {'NumberOfTimes': 1, 'Score': 5},
 'deal': {'NumberOfTimes': 1, 'Score': 10}}

word_vec_avg = {}
for k, v in mydict.items():
        word_vec_avg[k]={'AvgScore':v['Score']/v['NumberOfTimes']} #create a new dict and assign
```

Comment: In my actual dictionary (I only showed the first 4 key-value pairs in it, but it has 2596 key-value pairs), I get the following error with your code: `TypeError: string indices must be integers` on the line `word_vec_avg[k] = {"word": k, 'AvgScore': v['Score']/v['NumberOfTimes']}`, although when I try to print the new dictionary, I see that it contains 2404 items.