# Split string list into dictionary keys in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, split

I have a string 'request.context.user_id' and I want to split the string by '.' and use each element in the list as a dictionary key.  Is there a way to do this for lists of varying lengths without trying to hard code all the different possible list lengths after the split?

```
parts = string.split('.')
if len(parts)==1:
    data = [x for x in logData if x[parts[0]] in listX]
elif len(parts)==2:
    data = [x for x in logData if x[parts[0]][parts[1]] in listX]
else:
    print("Add more hard code")
```

listX is a list of string values that should be retrieved by x[parts[0]][parts[1]
logData is a list obtained from reading a json file and then the list can be read into a dataframe using json_normalize... the df portion is provided to give some context about its structure.. a list of dicts:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open(project_root+"filename") as f:
    logData = json.load(f)

df = json_normalize(logData)
```

Comment: What should the final dictionary look like?

Comment: And what do `listX` and `logData` look like?

Comment: Use a for loop from 0 to the legth of the list.

Comment: Python Regular Expression module could do this easily.

Comment: But how to make each element a key for the dictionary?

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.  I am not looking to create a dictionary... I am looking to use the list that was created by the split as keys in the existing dictionary which is an element of the logData list

Comment: @MrStutterZ your question would be much clearer if you showed what you're starting with and what you want in the end.

Comment: x is a dictionary and elements in parts list are the keys for dictionary 'x'
I am trying to read dictionary x

Answer (score 0):

I just realized in the comments you said that you didn't want to create a new dictionary but access an existing one `x` via chaining up the parts in the list.

#### (3.b) use a *`for loop`* to get/set the value in the key the path

In case you want to only read the value at the end of the path in

```py
import copy

def get_val(key_list, dict_):
    reduced = copy.deepcopy(dict_)
    for i in range(len(key_list)):
        reduced = reduced[key_list[i]]
    return reduced

# this solution isn't mine, see the link below
def set_val(dict_, key_list, value_):
    for key in key_list[:-1]:
        dict_ = dict_.setdefault(key, {})
    dict_[key_list[-1]] = value_
```

- `get_val()`
  Where the key_list is the result of `string.slit('.')` and `dict_` is the `x` dictionary in your case.
  You can leave out the `copy.deepcopy()` part, that's just for paranoid peeps like me - the reason is the python *dict is not immutable*, thus working on a *deepcopy* (a separate but exact copy in the memory) is a solution.
- `set_val()` As I said it's not my idea, credit to [@Bakuriu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13688108/8006845)
  `dict.setdefault(key, default_value)` will take care of non-existing keys in `x`.

#### (3) evaluating a string as code with `eval()` and/or `exec()`

So here's an <s>ugly</s> unsafe solution:

```py
def chainer(key_list):
    new_str = ''
    for key in key_list:
        new_str = "{}['{}']".format(new_str, key)
    return new_str

x = {'request': {'context': {'user_id': 'is this what you are looking for?'}}}
keys = 'request.context.user_id'.split('.')
chained_keys = chainer(keys)

# quite dirty but you may use eval() to evaluate a string
print( eval("x{}".format(chained_keys)) )

# will print
is this what you are looking for?
```

which is the innermost value of the mockup `x` dict

**I assume you could use this in your code like this**

```py
data = [x for x in logData if eval("x{}".format(chained_keys)) in listX]
# or in python 3.x with f-string
data = [x for x in logData if eval(f"x{chained_keys}") in listX]
```

...or something similar.

Similarly, you can use `exec()` to execute a string as code if you wanted to write to `x`, though it's just as dirty and unsafe.

```py
exec("x{} = '...or this, maybe?'".format(chained_keys))
print(x)

# will print
{'request': {'context': {'user_id': '...or this, maybe?'}}}
```

#### (2) <s>An actual solution</s> ***could be a `recursive function`*** as so:

```py
def nester(key_list):
    if len(key_list) == 0:
        return 'value'   # can change this to whatever you like
    else:
        return {key_list.pop(0): nester(key_list)}

keys = 'request.context.user_id'.split('.')  
# ['request', 'context', 'user_id']

data = nester(keys)
print(data)

# will result
{'request': {'context': {'user_id': 'value'}}}
```

#### (1) <s>A solution</s> with `list comprehension` for ***split the string by '.' and use each element in the list as a dictionary key***

```py
data = {}
parts = 'request.context.user_id'.split('.')

if parts:   # one or more items
    [data.update({part: 'value'}) for part in parts]

print(data)

# the result
{'request': 'value', 'context': 'value', 'user_id': 'value'}
```

You can overwrite the *values* in `data` afterwards.

Comment: they are nested keys

Comment: I see, that makes a difference... and my answer mostly useless

Comment: Updated my answer to handle them as nested dict keys. Left the flat dict solution too, just in case

Answer (score 0):

If you want arbitrary counts, that means you need a loop. You can use `get` repeatedly to drill through layers of dictionaries.

```py
parts = "request.context.user_id".split(".")
logData = [{"request": {"context": {"user_id": "jim"}}}]
listX = "jim"

def generate(logData, parts):
    for x in logData:
        ref = x
        # ref will be, successively, x, then the 'request' dictionary, then the
        # 'context' dictionary, then the 'user_id' value 'jim'. 
        for key in parts:
            ref = ref[key]
        if ref in listX:
            yield x


data = list(generate(logData, parts)))  # ['jim']
```