# using a single variable to index into nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Imagine you have a dictionary in python: `myDic = {'a':1, 'b':{'c':2, 'd':3}}`.  You can certainly set a variable to a key value and use it later, such as:

```
myKey = 'b'
myDic[myKey]
>>> {'c':2, 'd':3}
```

However, is there a way to somehow set a variable to a value that, when used as a key, will dig into sub dictionaries as well?  Is there a way to accomplish the following pseudo-code in python?

```
myKey = "['b']['c']"
myDic[myKey]
>>> 2
```

So first it uses 'b' as a key, and whatever is reurned it then uses 'c' as a key on that.  Obviously, it would return an error if the value returned from the first lookup is not a dictionary.

Comment: See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122566/in-a-python-dict-of-dicts-how-do-you-emulate-perls-auto-vivification-behavior/3122575#3122575)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is nothing you can put into a variable so that `myDict[myKey]` will dig into the nested dictionaries.

Here is a function that may work for you as an alternative:

```
def recursive_get(d, keys):
    if len(keys) == 1:
        return d[keys[0]]
    return recursive_get(d[keys[0]], keys[1:])
```

Example:

```
>>> myDic = {'a':1, 'b':{'c':2, 'd':3}}
>>> recursive_get(myDic, ['b', 'c'])
2
```

Comment: Ok, I had originally considered just implementing the recursive method you've shown here, but was holding out out see if there was something built-in to do the job because I also wanted this nested capability for setting values and checking if `nested_key in dic`.  But Since there doesn't seem to be an alternative, I'll take this answer and just implement any other functionality manually.

Answer (score 3):

No, not with a regular dict.  With `myDict[key]` you can only access values that are actually values of `myDict`.  But if `myDict` contains other dicts, the values of those nested dicts are not values of `myDict`.

Depending on what you're doing with the data structure, it may be possible to get what you want by using tuple keys instead of nested dicts.  Instead of having `myDic = {'b':{'c':2, 'd':3}}`, you could have `myDic = {('b', 'c'):2, ('b', 'd'): 3}`.  Then you can access the values with something like `myDic['b', 'c']`.  And you can indeed do:

```
val = 'b', 'c'
myDic[val]
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you cannot.  If you think about the way python works, it evaluates inside out, left to right.  `[]` is a shorthand for `__getitem__` in this case.  Thus you would need to parse the arguments you are passing into `__getitem__` (whatever you pass in) and handle that intelligently. If you wanted to have such behavior, you would need to subclass/write your own `dict` class.

Comment: ah, now I understand why I can't do that.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old question. There is no builtin function for that.

Compact solution using `functools.reduce` and `operator.getitem`:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem

d = {'a': {'b': ['banana', 'lemon']}}
p = ['a', 'b', 1]

v = reduce(getitem, p, d)
# 'lemon'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myDict = {'a':1, 'b':{'c':2, 'd':3}}
k = 'b'

myDict.get(k) should give
{'c':2, 'd':3}

and either
d.get(k)['c'] 
OR

k1 = 'c'
d.get(k).key(k1) should give 2
```